# GeneXus 16 .NET Web and WWP 12 - Column filter shows the 'Loading Data' message instead of displaying the data

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

We have cases where the Column filter shows the 'Loading Data' message instead of displaying the data.

Answer (score 1):

WorkWithPlus support provided the following documentation to assist with this issue:

http://docs.dvelopsoftware.com/WikiPlus/servlet/com.wiki.wiki?2600,Issue+with+Column+Filters,